# Transform raster of unknown SRID using proj4 in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, postgis-raster

In PostGIS is there any way to transform raster of unknown SRID using proj4 to EPSG:3857 without dumping polygons?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: basically, no if you don't know where it is then you can't position it

Comment: A raster doesn't have any polygons

Comment: You would still need some way to link the raster's bounding box or corner points or other points to a known coordinate system. Then you could georeference it, and then transform it to EPSG::3857